# htaccess: multiple sub folders and website access

Tags: .htaccess

I'm being stuck setting up my htaccess properly. Currently I have the following situation and file structure in my htdocs folder:

- .htaccess
- /website
- /clients/blabla
- /somefolder

As you might guess, the folder "website" contains all the files that should be accessible upon navigation to http://mydomain.com - this works fine with the current htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on 

# remove www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# subfolder
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/website/
RewriteRule (.*) /website/$1

# clean urls
RewriteRule ^website/([a-z0-9\-]+)$ website/$1.php
```

My problem: While I want my website to be accessible the way it is now I also want to be able to access http://mydomain.com/clients/blala and http://mydomain.com/somefolder etc... With my current htaccess this results in a 404 Error saying "The requested URL /website/clients/blabla was not found on this server."

What do I need to add / change to my htaccess to make this work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just need to add a couple more conditions to exclude them.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/clients/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/somefolder/
```

And have these in front of your Rewrite rule in the subfolder section. That will stop it embedding `/website/` into the URI if it already contains `/clients/` or `/somefolder/`

Answer (score 5):

This shoud work.

```
RewriteEngine on 

# remove www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# subfolder
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/website/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/somefolder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/client/blabla/
RewriteRule (.*) /website/$1

# clean urls
RewriteRule ^website/([a-z0-9\-]+)$ website/$1.php
```